# Is "running way" a used expression?

Tags: translation

I've seen this in a [French airport train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDGVAL):

[image: Image describing proper positioning of wheelchairs inside the train]

It indicates how wheelchairs should be positioned inside the train.

However, I find very few references to the expression "running way". Is this an actually used expression? Otherwise, what would be the best translation here?

Comment: Looks like a mistranslation for _direction of travel_ or _forward_.

Comment: Something like "parking orientation" would be more easily understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Sens de la marche*** is a French idiom which means ***facing the engine***.

*Concise Oxford Hachette French Dictionary* Third Edition, edited by Jean-Benoit Ormal-Grenon and Natalie Potter. Oxford University Press 2004 page 547.

It is there to tell you which way the train/bus is going to move. *Running way* is perhaps not a good expression for an English-speaking person to understand. But it is not something I recall seeing in Britain.

Comment: I know what *sens de la marche* means, my question was especifically about usage of the expression *running way*. My question was probably not very clear, but I'm more interested in knowing if and when such an expression might actually be used in English. But from what you say, I guess "never" would be a valid answer?

Comment: @anol *Running way* would be a puzzling thing to see in Britain. I'm not sure I would grasp what it meant. Of course if it became established as a sign, everyone would know what it meant. But I think *direction of travel* might be better.